# Counting from a column in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to count the number of instances of an element in a column of a Pandas Dataframe based on a set of criteria.  I am running into difficulty in a few places.

Here is what  I have up to this point.  It effectively reads the CSV, drops the duplicates, and sorts df2.  I am performing all of these steps in order to isolate the criteria I want to use in the future. Frankly, this may even be an extra step I do not need.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
# importing all required modules numpy, pyplot, and pandas

df= pd.read_csv('file.csv')
# reading the CSV file as a pandas dataframe

df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset="MRCEmp")
df2 = df2.sort_values(["CLNum"])
# creating duplicate dataframe eliminating duplicate pairs
# sorting df2 in ascending order by column "CLNum"

clmax = df2["CLNum"].max()
clmin = df2["CLNum"].min()
# creating variables as int to define the maximum and minimum of the "CLNum: column

for n in df2["CLNum"]:  

    if n not in df2["CLNum"]:

        n = n + 1

    elif n in df2["CLNum"]:
    
        print(df2.loc[df2["CLNum"] == n])
    
        n = n + 1
```

I should note that not all integers are represented in `df2["CLnum"]` that is why I inserted the first for loop.

When running this script however, not all of the rows are displayed.  `clmax = 728` and `clmin = 1`, but the final row displayed holds an n value of 283.  I cannot find why not all rows are displayed.

Comment: Your [mre] should always include a minimal example of any data - enough to reproduce/test. We don't have access to your `'file.csv'`.  In this case a minimal example of the DataFrame would work.

Comment: Something like this should work ->  len(df2[df2['column_name'] == 'value'])

Comment: I do not understand. It seems that you are checking the values of `CLnum` against itself. Maybe you are trying to check against different data frames?

Comment: Give a sample request, provide the criteria, and sample output. It will help us understand what you are looking for. There maybe an easier way to do things.

Answer (score -1):

Try pandas [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) function